# Where to find the scope of a secret in Azure Key-vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I need to add roles for my app service so that it can access the secret in Azure key-vault
where Can I find the scope for the secret?

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "GetKey" {
  scope              = ????????? # how can I find the scope for the secret here ?
  principal_id       = azurerm_web_app.this.identity.0.principal_id
  role_definition_name = "Get"
}
```

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment#example-usage-using-a-built-in-role

Answer (score 2):

The scope is built from the keyvault ID.  I used something like:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
# I think you need the following line as well
  enable_rbac_authorization       = true
...
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "GetKey" {
  scope              = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}/secrets/<your secret name>"
  principal_id       = azurerm_web_app.this.identity.0.principal_id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
}
```

As Jorgen pointed out, I think you can take a similar approach when using "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy"s but I haven't tested it.  That is where you can specify the "Get", "List", etc. permissions.

Comment: This is correct-ish. The scope url depends on the type of "secret" you are using. Possible scope URLs look like: `${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}/secrets/`, `${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}/keys/`, one for certificates, and so on.

Comment: and ${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}/certificates/ for certs ;)

Answer (score 0):

To grant access to secrets you need to use azurerm_key_vault_access_policy as well. Key Vault has a level of permissions in addition to resource-permissions that control access to secrets, keys and certificates. Here is an example: [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy: Example Usage](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy#example-usage)

Comment: The OP is using `azurerm_role_assignment` which implies RBAC permissions. The vault can only use one type of auth at a time (either RBAC or Vault Access Policy). FYI this answer applies to Vault Access Policy, and conflicts with the RBAC based answer.